# NetMessagingBinding polling interval and concurrecy

Tags: wcf, azure, appfabric, servicebus

I'm implementing Service Bus client to receive queue messages and need to estimate monthly charges for the usage.

Based on what I read I can control polling directly by using [QueueClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.aspx)

or I can use WCF model via netMessagingBinding.

It is my understanding that netMessagingBinding does polling itself however I could not find a definitive answer as to how often it polls. Also, how many concurrent connections does it keep?

Can anyone assist me with an answer or point me to the right article that describes this in detail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The netMessagingBinding follows the same defaults that you have for operation timeouts and hence would be a similar experience to calling Receive() in a loop. Currently that translates to 60 seconds for a single call and if no message is found for an entire month then that would add up to about 14cents of cost.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect answer to my question!